# How to incentivise users to contribute data back to my community

Tags: user-behavior, user-engagement, gamification

I trying to build community x, which is kind of a stack exchange for domain y. At the center of this community would be data pertaining to domain y. However, in order to get the data, I need users to upload it. The data would be generated by their use of a product which I can give away for free, whereas my competitors charge about $50 for the product. So, I'm wondering if there is a list of techniques I can use to incentivise users to contribute the data back to the site.

Of course, there are all the common gamification techniques. Any others? For example, since I'm the only place able to give the product away for free, I was thinking about something like charging $25 for it, but if the users upload the data, they are refunded the amount they paid. Not sure this would work though, since once the money has been paid, it might be an out-of-mind-out-of-sight kind of thing and they wouldn't bother sending the data back to the site.

Comment: You seem to need data but you don't really explain what the product is... is it possible to build reporting back to you into the product? This makes it zero-work on the part of the user and (assuming you give them the opportunity to opt-out), shouldn't have much in the way of privacy issues... does the product allow this sort of thing or could it be configured in such a way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say what the product is for confidentiality reasons, but, no, since the product isn't software, I can't build reporting back into it.

Comment: I would think gamification works best for software product.. even if its not a software product, maybe you can build an interface which allows users to easily upload data, or automatically upload data at periodic intervals. If there is too much work involved for the user.. they are probably not going to be willing to upload data.